# Should i go with angular 2 already?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm starting a new project for internal use in my company. It won't need to be released sooner than in six months. Is it reasonable to start writing it in Angular 2 or just go with Angular 1? As from their github, they already have made 44% progress reaching beta stage milestone. How much, do you think, Angular 2 API will change until reaching final stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular2 is  not polished, and the APIs will change. So if you plan to do a short, small project , you probably want to stick to Angular1 for a little while. But if you're starting and want to set up a nice base for your projects to come, you could start now using Angular2.

Answer (score 0):

comparing to ng-2 to ng-1 the amount of effort needed for ng-2 is very less compared to ng-1. in ng-2 all the directives are removed and i hoe in future ng-2 can be more easy to code and deploy external services . if you are already an ng-1 developer then its good that you can do your project in this